How to calculate the interpolating values of the IFFT of a zero padded frequency domain vector?
Say if $x \!\left[ 0 \right]$, $x \!\left[ 1 \right]$, $x \!\left[ 2 \right]$, $x \!\left[ 3 \right]$ are time domain data. After taking FFT of the sequence, we get $X \!\left[ 0 \right]$, $X \!\left[ 1 \right]$, $X \!\left[ 2 \right]$, $X \!\left[ 3 \right]$. If we zero pad the sequence like $X \!\left[ 0 \right], \ldots ,X \!\left[ 3 \right], 0, 0, 0, 0$ and then take IFFT of the zero-padded signal(say the output is $y \!\left[ n \right]$), I see that a scaled version of original data symbols $x \!\left[ 0 \right]$ to $x \!\left[ 3 \right]$ are occurring at a regular interval in the final output $y \!\left[ n \right]$ which is obvious.
But my question is, how should I calculate the interpolating values of $y \!\left[ n \right]$, i.e., those values which are occurring within the original symbols $x \!\left[ 0 \right]$ to $x \!\left[ 3 \right]$.
For example, for the above question, $y \!\left[ 0 \right] \sim x \!\left[ 0 \right]$, $y \!\left[ 2 \right] \sim x \!\left[ 1 \right]$, $y \!\left[ 4 \right] \sim x \!\left[ 2 \right]$, because the length is doubled by zero padding. But how the values $y \!\left[ 1 \right]$, $y \!\left[ 3 \right]$, $y \!\left[ 5 \right]$ can be calculated? Does $y \!\left[ 1 \right]$ depend on $x \!\left[ 0 \right]$ and $x \!\left[ 1 \right]$ only as it lies within the region of $x \!\left[ 0 \right]$ and $x \!\left[ 1 \right]$? Can it be considered as a weighted sum of $x \!\left[ 0 \right]$ and $x \!\left[ 1 \right]$?

The title of the question mentions "FFT of a zero padded time domain signal" however, in the question itself the FFT is zero padded? Assuming the FFT result is zero padded, have you googled "FFT Upsampling sinc-interpolation"?
